# Canary Win11 PC becomes unresponsive and locks up when accessed via remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, remote-access

I am running the latest insider canary build of Win11, and haven't had any problems in the past 1.5yr until now. Whenever I connect remotely to my machine, first Windows becomes unresponsive (can still move my mouse cursor and click things and open start but nothing opens or executes including shutdown and reboot) and then fully locks up/completely freezes requiring a power cycle before it'll do anything again (method of remote doesn't seem to make any difference, RDP Parsec and Google Remote Desktop all trigger this behavior).

When I'm on the machine locally none of this occurs and Windows works flawlessly.

Anybody who has any suggestions? SFC and DISM both finished without any detected corruption and this also occurs when my AV is disabled (It's currently locked up and I am not near my machine right now, so until I have cycled the power when I'm back home I am unable to inspect/collect logs or any other data)

**EDIT:** I just found somebody in the Insider community who has the same symptoms but on a local log-in, for him the trouble starts when he tries to open Steam so next time I've been able to power-cycle it I'll have to try if opening steam when on the actual machine would trigger the symptoms for me as well, because if that's the case it has nothing to do with the fact that I'm remote

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/new-canary-build-killed-my-steam/m-p/3807008/highlight/false#M21606

Comment: Make sure it is fully up to date (today is Patch Tuesday) and see if that helps. If not report the bug in the Feedback Hub. I have an Insider machine beside me here and I can access it with Remote Desktop.

Comment: I am up to date, and the connection works for a little while (just tried with parsec, next time i've been near my machine to reset it I'll test more with RDP too) untill all those symptoms begin and ultimately the machine locks up hard and becomes unreachable because of that. (the first time this happened is 1.5~2 weeks ago)

Comment: I just found somebody in the Insider community who has the same symptoms but on a local log-in, for him the trouble starts when he tries to open Steam so next time I've been able to powercycle it I'll have to try if opening steam when on the actual machine would trigger the symptoms for me as well, because if that's the case it has nothing to do with the fact that I'm remote 

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, this issue has been fixed through an update.

Comment: Which update? Do you have an id?